# Trouble connecting to Battlefield 3 servers

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

I'm hoping someone can help diagnose what my problem is trying to connect to servers playing Battlefield 3. For some reason, for example, I can only connect to about 2 out of 10 servers. I have a brand new Dell XPS that can handle the game without any problems, my internet connection is good, I can average about 1.5 - 2 MBps download speed, upload speed about 1.5 MBps average.

I have noticed that most of the time the servers I can only connect to have a ping rate of lower than 70 if that helps any, rarely can I connect to a server with a ping higher than 100. Some of the errors I have seen on the battlelog screen are:

(Mind you the wording could be a little different, I'm trying to remember these errors of the top of my head seeing as I'm not in front of my gaming computer right now and don't have access to it at this time)

- Disconnected from EA Online(1)
- Could not join server
- Disconnected from Server

Once I am in front of my laptop I can update this with the correct wording of the errors, unless someone already knows what I'm talking about and knows how to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen these too, but not as common. The issue is that these can also appear if BF3 crashed.

Try to rule out BF3 crashing (we can't even tell when it crashes or not, a disconnect and crash look the same). Close all programs, run a chkdsk and all that. Then when you go to play join a server and don't touch anything. Let it connect and open, see what happens.

If you don't think it's a game crash, try connecting directly to your modem (I assume you're connected to a router) and see if that helps. If it does, the router sounds like the issue.